# Heroku/Rails error, logs not very helpful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile

I have recently developed my first Ruby on Rails app and have tried to deploy it to Heroku, however when I try to load the app URL, it just returns with this page:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

Here are my logs:

```
2015-01-27T14:11:44.782093+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by tom@tomoakley.me
2015-01-27T14:11:45.419564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-01-27T14:11:48.394740+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21006 -e production`
2015-01-27T14:11:49.304740+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-27 14:11:50] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179123+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179120+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179121+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179126+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:35:in `run'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179124+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179133+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179152+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179150+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179130+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179128+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179161+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-27 14:11:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179127+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179160+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-27 14:11:50] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179131+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179151+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.179153+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-01-27T14:11:50.265926+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-01-27T14:11:50.265932+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:39482
2015-01-27T14:11:50.265936+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-01-27T14:11:50.265934+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-01-27T14:11:50.265937+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-01-27T14:11:51.162075+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-01-27T14:11:52.030623+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-27 14:11:52] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-01-27T14:11:52.030600+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-27 14:11:52] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-01-27T14:11:52.030938+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-27 14:11:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=21006
2015-01-27T14:11:52.681188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-01-27T14:12:57.646409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.biblequot.es request_id=8125c7b1-2590-4162-b98f-0b849febe74e fwd="94.175.136.230" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=1175ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

I was previously trying to work out how to keep the Secret Keys in `config/secrets.yml` from being on Github (the repo will be public) and tried to install `GPG` and use `dotgpg` (using the guide [here](https://bugsnag.com/blog/use-gpg-to-hide-rails-secrets)) but I couldn't get it to work properly so took it out of my Gemfile, which I've copied in below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use font-awesome!
gem 'font-awesome-sass'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

And also for good measure, here is my `config/enviroment/production.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.configure do


 # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

end
```

Sorry for putting so much stuff here, I just hope someone can resolve my problem quickly :) Also as a bonus, what's the best way to hide the secret keys in secrets.yml? Does it matter if the development and test keys are there? (the production key is hidden in an environment variable). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your logs, it looks like your application received a Sigterm, but when you see the rails error message 
"We're sorry, but something went wrong." It mean the server started, and the error is inside your rails application.

So we need to see more of your logs to help you.

The easiest way for environement variable is to create a .env.sample with examples of environement variable and every developer creates it's own .env file and use dotenv-rails with `gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]` inside your `Gemfile`

You can even replace your database.yml with :

`DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/database_name`

But dotgpg looks great, I will try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

in your project directory, run

```
heroku run console
```

it should give you more info